# Talk to smart home device over Apple HomeKit Protocol

Tags: ios, homekit

I've the following problem: I want to talk to smart home devices (like Elgato Eve, https://www.elgato.com/en/eve) through an own app. But the devices just support currently Apple HomeKit protocol. I don't want to use any official app or my iPhone to do this!

Is it possible to provide a way through my app to talk to the devices? Like "stubbing" the HomeKit Protocol? Has anyone ever done something like this or are there already any proof of concepts?

Answer (score 1):

Elgato has a BTLE module called [Eve Core](https://www.elgato.com/en/eve-core). The product description says it is just a bare BTLE HomeKit gateway for new HomeKit devices but it may help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10839357)

Comment: I think you are right sometimes, but not in this case. The answer linked to a specific hardware - if the manufacturer stops the production of that certain hardware the entire answer will become obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Homekit accessory devices, like Eve, include an Apple-designed chip that encrypts messages between it and iOS for security.  You'd have to defeat that...which raises the question of why you'd want to.